# vSphere client connection to vCSA 5.5 fail to connect

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi5.5

vSphere client connection to vCSA 5.5 fail to connect remote server.

I work with this machine for over 3 years but now
I get this error when I trying to connect to vCSA to manage my ESXi(s):

```
vSphere client could not connect to "192.xxx.xxx.xxx"
 An unknown connection error occurred.
(The request failed because of a connection failure.(Unable to connect to the remote server))
```

**Tip: When I turn back time of the vCSA machine, it connects normally!**

Now I can connect to ESXi hosts directly but am unable to connect vCSA.
Any solution?
Is it related to certificate and SSL?